# Horizontal scroll bar not maintaining position on post back

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a page that has a panel with a horizontal scroll bar:

```
<div id="pagingPanelDiv">
    <asp:Panel ID="pagingPanel" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="1275px" ScrollBars="Horizontal" Wrap="false"></asp:Panel>
</div>
```

[image]

I want the scroll bar to maintain its position on postback, such as when one of the buttons within the scrollbar is pushed. Hence I added MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true":

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master/template.master" AutoEventWireup="true" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeFile="report1.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_report1" %>
```

This isn't working. How do I get the desired results?

Comment: Might be a better idea to remove the need for a horizontal scroll bar.  No one likes scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the scroll position of that `<div>` yourself into a hidden `<input />`, persist it between sessions, and load it - ASP.NET's `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` only stores the scrolling coordinates of the main viewport, not any scrollable children.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this approach?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try wrapping the section of the page with the horizontal scroll in an UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="pagingPanelDiv">
            <asp:Panel ID="pagingPanel" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="1275px" 
                ScrollBars="Horizontal" Wrap="false"></asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```